MoveIt2 does not recognize when goal pose is reached (MoveIt2: Completed trajectory execution with status TIMED OUT)
Summary
MoveIt2 does not seem to recognize if the robot reached the goal, resulting in the robot waiting in the reached goal pose until MoveIt2 times out.
Setup
We are using a UR10 in combination with the Universal Robots ROS2 Driver and MoveIt2.
The driver is running on the robot and MoveIt2 is running on an external server (but the issue remains if both are running on the robot).
Furthermore, we are using a the joint trajectory controller, however, we tried to use the scaled joint trajectory controller but with the same result.
Error
After starting everything, we see the correct joint states inside of rviz. We then use the MotionPlanning inside of rviz (planner: ompl) to select a goal pose, plan and execute the trajectory.
1 We then get the following output inside the MoveIt2 terminal:
[move group-1] [INFO] [1713261446.691986517) [moveit ros.plan execution]: Planning attempt 1 of at most 1 
[move group-1] [INFO] [1713261446.691997688] [moveit move group capabilities base.move group capability]: Using planning pipeline 'ompl'
[move group-1] [INFO] [1713261445.692991837] [moveit.ompl planning model based planning context]: Planner configuration 'arm[RRTConnectkConfigDefault]' will use planner 'geometric::RRTConnect'. Additional configuration parameters will be set when the planner is constructed.
[move group 1] [INFO] [1713261446.828756079] [moveit.plugins.moveit simple controller manager]: Returned 1 controllers in list
[move group-1] [INFO] [1713261446.828783640] [moveit.plugins.moveit simple controller manager): Returned 1 controllers in list
[move group-1] [INFO] [1713261446.828864361] [moveit ros.trajectory execution manager]: Validating trajectory with allowed start tolerance 0.02 
[move group-1] [INFO] [1713261446.835697127] [moveit ros trajectory execution manager]: Starting trajectory execution...
[move group-1] [INFO] [1713261446.835779581] [moveit plugins.moveit simple controller manager): Returned 1 controllers in list
[move group-1] [INFO] [1713261446.835809728] [moveit.plugins.moveit simple controller manager: Returned 1 controllers in list
[move group-1] [INFO] [1713261446.836248117] [moveit.simple controller manager follow joint trajectory controller handle): sending trajectory to/kairosAB/arm/joint_trajectory_controller
[move group-1] [INFO] [1713261446.852023214) [moveit.simple controller manager follow joint trajectory controller handle]: /kairosAB/arm/joint_trajectory_controller started execution
[move group-1] [INFO] [1713261446.852083196] [moveit.simple_controller manager, follow joint trajectory controller handle]: Goal request accepted!

1 And inside the Driver terminal:
[ur_ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1713261446.85...][kairosAB.arm.joint_trajectory_controller]: Accepted new action goal

2 After reaching the end pose we get the following inside the driver
[ur_ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1713261463.42...][kairosAB.arm.joint_trajectory_controller]: Goal reached, success!

2 After a while (2 to 3 seconds after reaching the goal) we get the following error from the MoveIt2 terminal:
[move group-1] [WARN] [17132614.541158495] [moveit.simple_controller_manager.follow_joint trajectory_contr oller handle]: waitForExecution timed out
[move_group-1] [ERROR] [1713261467.541217936] [moveit_ros.trajectory_execution_manager]: Controller is taking too long to execute trajectory (the expected upper bound for the trajectory execution was 20.689018 seconds). Stopping trajectory.
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1713261467.541253242][moveit.simple_controller_manager.follow_joint_trajectory_controller_handle]: Cancelling execution for/kairosAB/arm/joint_trajectory_controller
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1713261467.543623764] [moveit_ros.trajectory_execution_manager]: Completed trajectory execution with status TIMED OUT
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1713261467.545861768][moveit_move_group_default_capabilities.move_action_capability]: Timeout reached

Insights
We think, that MoveIt2 somehow does not recognize that the goal pose was reached and because of that after a while the time for the execution runs out and the timeout error is thrown. However, we could not really fix that by adjusting the goal threshold values.
Interestingly, if we execute a trajectory once and the goal pose is reached after which MoveIt2 times out and therefore fails. If we then plan for the same goal again and execute it, MoveIt2 says that it already reached the goal.
Code
Here is how we have defined the joint_trajectory_controller inside the moveit2 config (we tried lot of different values also negative):
define: &traj_threshold 0.6
define: &goal_threshold -0.6

kairosAB:
  arm:
    joint_trajectory_controller:
      ros__parameters:
        joints:
          - kairosAB_arm_shoulder_pan_joint
          - kairosAB_arm_shoulder_lift_joint
          - kairosAB_arm_elbow_joint
          - kairosAB_arm_wrist_1_joint
          - kairosAB_arm_wrist_2_joint
          - kairosAB_arm_wrist_3_joint
        command_interfaces:
          - position
        state_interfaces:
          - position
          - velocity
        state_publish_rate: 125.0
        action_monitor_rate: 20.0
        allow_partial_joints_goal: false
        constraints:
          stopped_velocity_tolerance: 0.1
          goal_time: 0.6
          kairosAB_arm_shoulder_pan_joint: { trajectory: *traj_threshold, goal: *goal_threshold }
          kairosAB_arm_shoulder_lift_joint: { trajectory: *traj_threshold, goal: *goal_threshold }
          kairosAB_arm_elbow_joint: { trajectory: *traj_threshold, goal: *goal_threshold }
          kairosAB_arm_wrist_1_joint: { trajectory: *traj_threshold, goal: *goal_threshold }
          kairosAB_arm_wrist_2_joint: { trajectory: *traj_threshold, goal: *goal_threshold }
          kairosAB_arm_wrist_3_joint: { trajectory: *traj_threshold, goal: *goal_threshold }

# MoveIt uses this configuration for controller management

trajectory_execution:
  allowed_execution_duration_scaling: 1.2
  allowed_goal_duration_margin: 0.8
  allowed_start_tolerance: 0.02
  trajectory_duration_monitoring: false

moveit_controller_manager: moveit_simple_controller_manager/MoveItSimpleControllerManager

moveit_simple_controller_manager:
  controller_names:
    - /kairosAB/arm/joint_trajectory_controller

  /kairosAB/arm/joint_trajectory_controller:
    type: FollowJointTrajectory
    action_ns: follow_joint_trajectory
    default: true
    joints:
      - kairosAB_arm_shoulder_pan_joint
      - kairosAB_arm_shoulder_lift_joint
      - kairosAB_arm_elbow_joint
      - kairosAB_arm_wrist_1_joint
      - kairosAB_arm_wrist_2_joint
      - kairosAB_arm_wrist_3_joint
    action_ns: follow_joint_trajectory
    default: true

Inside the driver we defined the joint_trajectory_controller like this:
kairosAB:
  arm:
    joint_trajectory_controller:
      ros__parameters:
        joints:
          - kairosAB_arm_shoulder_pan_joint
          - kairosAB_arm_shoulder_lift_joint
          - kairosAB_arm_elbow_joint
          - kairosAB_arm_wrist_1_joint
          - kairosAB_arm_wrist_2_joint
          - kairosAB_arm_wrist_3_joint
        command_interfaces:
          - position
        state_interfaces:
          - position
          - velocity
        state_publish_rate: 125.0
        action_monitor_rate: 20.0
        allow_partial_joints_goal: false
        constraints:
          stopped_velocity_tolerance: 0.05
          goal_time: 0.6
          kairosAB_arm_shoulder_pan_joint: { trajectory: 0.4, goal: 0.2 }
          kairosAB_arm_shoulder_lift_joint: { trajectory: 0.4, goal: 0.2 }
          kairosAB_arm_elbow_joint: { trajectory: 0.4, goal: 0.2 }
          kairosAB_arm_wrist_1_joint: { trajectory: 0.4, goal: 0.2 }
          kairosAB_arm_wrist_2_joint: { trajectory: 0.4, goal: 0.2 }
          kairosAB_arm_wrist_3_joint: { trajectory: 0.4, goal: 0.2 }

How can you help us
Even a workaround or an insight on how the ExecutionManager of MoveIt2 works would be helpful. For example: if you could send MoveIt2 a message when the goal is reached telling MoveIt2 that the goal is reached, so the timeout does not happen.
Thank you very much in advance.
